# How is this valid syntax?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Fiddling with javascript and arrays, and this passed as valid syntax, how?

```
var x = [asd = {a: 10, b: 20}]
```

this line is to meet question quality standards.

Comment: Evaluating first `asd = {a: 10, b: 20}` and then using the value of `asd` as the first element in array. **Evaluation Steps** **1.** `asd = {a: 10, b: 20}` **2** `[asd]` **3.** `var x = [...]`

Comment: @Tushar Thanks ! and `asd` is now a global variable?

Comment: [asd :{a: 10, b: 20}]

Comment: @AmitRamoliya no, that is not what it means.

Comment: @ta-run yes, it become a global variable, this syntax should not work in strict mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some ways to achieve the thing you want:

**Create the object using object literal**

```
var asd = {a: 10, b: 20};
```

**Or create the object using object constructor**

```
   var asd = new Object();
   asd.a = 10;
   asd.b = 20;
```

And Then push this object into your array.

The array again can be created in the following ways:

**Using array literal**

```
var x = [asd];
```

**Or using array constructor:**

```
var x = new Array;
   x.push(asd);
```

Comment: Is it `new Array()` also note that provided code in snippet works as well!

Comment: Yes you are correct but new Array also works if simply used for creating a constructor.

Answer (score 3):

Let us separate and see:

The code you write can change to below:

```
// it not have the `var` like other answer say
asd = {a: 10, b: 20}
var x = [asd]
```

**But be careful about using it, it can cause global define variable.**

And if it in `strict mode`,**this will not work**, because the **Implicitly defined** global is not allow.